# Converting Excel VBA for a single sheet to workbook wide

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following VBA code that functions properly when put in the code sheet for a single worksheet within an Excel workbook:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Target = Int(Target) + (Target - Int(Target)) * 100 / 60
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I want to change the code so that I can put it in the workbook code sheet rather than the code sheet of each individual worksheet, and to do so came up with the following that I thought would function. However, it does not.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Change(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Do nothing if not entering data in time cell
    If (Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("F:F")) Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheets As Variant: sheets = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    Dim sheet As Variant     

    For Each sheet In sheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet)
        If Not Intersect(ws.Range("F:F"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            Target = Int(Target) + (Target - Int(Target)) * 100 / 60
        End If
        If Int(Target) = 0 Then
            Target.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Is there an obvious error there so that I can be pointed in the correct direction?

Comment: The proper event is `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: Well for one thing you need to have error-handling.  Otherwise, if you get an error, you could end up leaving all of your events disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your `ThisWorkbook` Code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim hr As Boolean
Dim sheets As Variant: sheets = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
Dim sheet As Variant
On Error GoTo ext
For Each sheet In sheets
    If sheet = Sh.Name Then
        hr = True
    End If
Next sheet

If Not Intersect(Sh.Range("F:F"), Target) Is Nothing And hr Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = Int(Target) + (Target - Int(Target)) * 100 / 60
    If Int(Target) = 0 Then
        Target.ClearContents
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ext:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I believe this will do what you were trying.

Edit:

As per @RBarryYoung, it was also missing the error check to ensure that it turns back on the Events.

Comment: Once again, you nailed what I was needing. Thanks.

Comment: @rkent see edit I put in an error check to ensure that the events get turned back on.